# Plotting 3D Decision Boundary From MLPClassifier By Using make_classification Dataset

Tags: matplotlib, scikit-learn

I used make_classification library and MLPClassifier from sklearn. However, I could not make my points separated like on [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hb3I.png). And this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feV9l.png) is what my plot shows. Could you help me to separate the points or what is the problem?

My code is:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
X,y=make_classification(n_samples=550, n_features=10, n_informative=2,random_state=0)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test , y_train , y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)


from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
mlp= MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(), max_iter=300, random_state=0)
    
clf = mlp.fit(X_test, y_test)

z = lambda x,y: (-clf.intercepts_[0]-clf.coefs_[0][0]*x -clf.coefs_[0][1]*y) / clf.coefs_[0][2]
                  
tmp = np.linspace(-5,5,30)
x,y = np.meshgrid(tmp,tmp)

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(X_test[y_test==0,0]+2, X_test[y_test==0,1]-2, X_test[y_test==0,2]-5, c='b', marker='^')
ax.scatter(X_test[y_test==1,0]-2, X_test[y_test==1,1]+2, X_test[y_test==1,2]+5, c='r', marker='o')

ax.plot_surface(x, y, z(x,y))
ax.view_init(30, 60)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing (seriously) wrong on your code. You need to set some parameters to get what you desire. First, you may need larger figure.

```
# To set figure size other than the default value, specify width and height
fig = plt.figure( figsize=(8,8) )
```

Secondly, for the size of markers in `scatter()` function:

```
# To set marker size, use `s=number` as an option
ax.scatter(X_test[y_test==0,0]+2, X_test[y_test==0,1]-2, X_test[y_test==0,2]-5, \
    c='b', marker='^', s=3)
ax.scatter(X_test[y_test==1,0]-2, X_test[y_test==1,1]+2, X_test[y_test==1,2]+5, \
    c='r', marker='o', s=3)
```

The plot should be similar to this:

[image: scat3d]